# PHP Variables & Optimsation

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

This may well be a very basic PHP 101 question, but I was wondering if there is any real benefit in collecting data in variables in one query (when possible), rather than throughout a page effectively on the fly.

For example;

```
<?php

    $title = get_field('title');
    $paragraph = get_field('paragraph');
    $url = get_field('url');

?>

<div class="box">

    <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
    <p><?php echo $paragraph; ?></p>
    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"></a>

</div>
```

vs;

```
<div class="box">

    <h1><?php the_field('title'); ?></h1>
    <p><?php the_field('paragraph'); ?></p>
    <a href="<?php the_field('url'); ?>">Read More</a>

</div>
```

Does either method have an impact on performance?

Comment: No. Do whatever makes maintaining it easiest for you.

Comment: while above comment is true, I'd suggest you try to avoid spaghetti code like this. Separate code from markup. You will thank me later.

Comment: Thanks both. @MarcinOrlowski could you explain what you mean?